# Checking when SKPhysicsBody has stopped moving?

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Is there anyway of calculating when an `SKPhysicsBody` comes to rest (or rather its velocity gets very small) so that you can remove it from the physics simulation. I have tried watching the velocity but there are two issues. (1) on any given bounce there is a point at the apex where the object has little velocity, (2) when the `SKPhysicsBody` has visibly finished bouncing the **velocity.dy** still shows a pretty large number (i.e. 30+) even though for all intents the body is now at rest. Just curious if there is anything available I might have missed for checking when a body is no longer moving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKPhysicsBody` has a boolean `resting` property that the physics world turns on when deemed at rest - that might be what you're looking for. Not sure that will work though in your case since you can't really set the threshold when it triggers.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, I totally missed that. Thats exactly what I was after, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the [`resting` property of `SKPhysicsBody`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/resting).

From the linked documentation,

> This property is automatically set to YES by the physics simulation
>   when it determines that the body is at rest. This means that the body
>   is at rest on another body in the system. Resting bodies do not
>   participate in the physics simulation until an impulse is applied to
>   the object or another object collides with it. This improves the
>   performance of the physics simulation. If all bodies in the world are
>   resting, then the entire simulation is at rest, reducing the number of
>   calculations that are performed by the physics world.